# Find the x and y coordinates of a certain point of a moving object

Tags: objective-c, math, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

If you understand objective c very well, then just read the last 2 sentences. The rest of this just summarizes the last 2 sentances:

---

So I have two sprites, the lower arm and the upper arm. I set the anchor points to `ccp(0.5f,0.0f)` So lets say that the following dashes represent the lower arm, the anchorpoint is the dash in parenthesis: (-)------ . So the object is rotating around this point (the CGPoint at the moment is `ccp(100,55)`).

What I need is, if the lower arm is rotating around the dash in parenthesis: (-)-----o the circle represents the point I want. I'm basically connecting the two arms and trying to make the movement look nice... Both arms are 17 pixels long (which means that if the lower arm is pointing straight up, the CGPoint of the circle is `ccp(100,72)`, and if the arm was pointing straight down, the circle would be `ccp(100,38)`.

What equation would I use so that I could set the position of the upper arm equal to the position of the lower arm's rotating CGPoint, represented as a circle in the 2nd paragraph of this question. Like... _*,/  the _* represents the lower arm, the comma represents the point I want, and the / represent the upper arm.

So lower and upper arm = 17 pixels long, anchor point for both is (0.5f,0.0f), how do I find the point opposite of the anchor point for the lower arm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

x = 100 + 17 * cos(θ)
y = 55 + 17 * sin(θ)

Comment: The angle is always changing... do you know a function or something that would find the angle of the sprite?

Comment: I don't know, is it Cocoa or Cocos2D? How are you changing the angle? Is it a transform? If that's the case I can probably explain how to calculate the point directly from the transform. Another conceptually more complicated but simpler code is to define the transform of the upper arm as a concatenation with the transform of the lower arm.

Comment: Well I would have no idea how to " transform of the upper arm as a concatenation with the transform of the lower arm" but its in cocos2d, The angle will change from -75 degrees to at most 75-80sh degrees... but it will be changing all the time

Answer (score 1):

You need to find what the angle of rotation is. I'm not that familiar with objective c, but if you're using a rotation function there's most likely an angle component somewhere you can reference.

From there you can use trigonometry to find the components of your x and y change.

For x it will be: (anchor x) + (length of arm) * cosine(angle of rotation)

And for y it will be: (anchor y) + (length of arm) * sine(angle of rotation)

Also, make sure you know whether the angle is in radians or degrees, you might have to convert based on the sine/cosine functions.